# < and > operators on pair

Tags: c++, std-pair

How does the < and > operators work on pair when first value of pair is equal? I have read 2 different concepts on this which has confused me.

eg.

```
pair<int,int> p1(5,10);
pair<int,int> p2(5,12);
```

What should be the answer of p1 > p2 ?

Comment: `p1 > p2` is false in the example you give because 10 > 12 is false

Comment: When in doubt take a look at [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp): _"Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically by operator<, that is, compares the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the second elements."_

Comment: What are the two different concepts that you have read?

Answer (score 3):

As usual the answer is in the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp):

> Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically by operator<, that is, compares
> the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the
> second elements.
>
> #### Return value:
>
> `operator<`
>
> If `lhs.first<rhs.first`, returns `true`. Otherwise, if
> `rhs.first<lhs.first`, returns `false`. Otherwise, if
> `lhs.second<rhs.second`, returns `true`. Otherwise, returns `false`
>
> `operator>`
>
> rhs < lhs